# What is in and out on delegate in c#?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, method-signature

In c# code, i found this implement.

I tried to find out what this in and out meaning, but only explanation of out keyword in there.

So what these in and out keyword do?

```
public delegate Tb Reader<in Ta, out Tb>( Ta a );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` parameter specifies that the type parameter is contravariant -you can pass in a class that Ta inherits from.

The `out` parameter specifies that the parameter is covariant -> you can use more derived types.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier) for the in modifer, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) for the out modifier

Answer (score -1):

They make possible to do like below example.

```
Reader<string,object> first = someString => return someObject;
Reader<object,string> second= someObject => return someString;
first=second;
```